# Invoking a method in another method in Java

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write a method that decides if an integer is curious or not *(which are equal to the sum of the factorial of their digits)*.

I have written a factorial method.

```
public int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n==0) return 1;
    else return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Then another method which returns true if number is curious.

```
public boolean isCurious(int y)
{
    String converted = String.valueOf(y);
    int sum = 0; //sum of factorials
    for(int i=0; i<converted.length(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + factorial(converted.charAt(i));
    }

    if (sum==y) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work. *factorial(converted.charAt(i))* Most probably this part is wrong. What is the problem?

Comment: WHat does "doesn't work" mean? Show complete, valid code sample.

Comment: replace `converted.charAt(i)` by `converted.charAt(i) - '0'`

Comment: These codes are in MyMath class. I created a tester class and created a new object of this class called math1. Then, in main method i wrote
System.out.println(math1.isCurious(145));

It shows false.

Comment: maybe you will get a falsy result (or even a StackOverflowError), you have to check if the integer is under 0, so you don't process and throw an exception, because there isn't factorial for negative numbers, but in your case, if you supply a negative integer to factorial method, the recursive calls won't stop (defensive programming for escaping from bugs), but if you alocate moooooore memory to Java, you will get an integer overflow, and that integer will be 0, and you will get a falsy result :)

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, in general case (where locale is unknown). Just proposed quick solution. Actually, `Integer.toString()` produces standard 0-9 digits, no need to care about it here. The only thing to care is possible `-` sign, as it will issue stack overflow here.

Comment: btw, `if (sum==y) return true;
    else return false;` can be shortened to `return sum == y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because the `char` representation of a number is not the same as the integer value of that number. It's the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoding of that character. If you want to convert a `char` into its `int` value, you should subtract `'0'` (the `char` zero) from it.

So your code should be changed to this:

```
sum = sum + factorial(converted.charAt(i) - '0');
```

Comment: Or: `sum += factorial(Character.getNumericValue(converted.charAt(i)));`

Comment: Or `sum += factorial(Character.digit(converted.charAt(i), 10));`

Comment: No, it's the Unicode/UTF-16 encoding of the character. `'0'` also uses the UTF-16 encoding. And arithmetic on the encoding of characters in the range of those digits miraculously work.

Comment: @TomBlodget True. All the relevant characters here are the same as in ASCII though, which is easier to wrap one's head around.

Answer (score 0):

You used int as parameter in **isCurious function**. You should used **string** as parameter. Below you passed the **factorial(converted.charAt(i))** is changed
to **factorial(converted.charAt(i) - '0')** to behave that character like an int value.

The code snippet is below:

```
>   public boolean isCurious(String y)  {
>       String converted = String.valueOf(y);
>       int sum = 0; //sum of factorials
>       for(int i=0; i<converted.length(); i++)
>       {
>           sum = sum + factorial(converted.charAt(i) - '0');
>           
>       }
> 
>       int temp = Integer.parseInt(y);
>       if (sum==temp) return true;
>       else return false;  
   }
```

call this method from main fuction like this:

> System.out.print(isCurious("1")); //pass string in parameters

**factorial(converted.charAt(i) - '0');**. You can understand this line by the help of ASCII.

Suppose **converted.charAt(i)** has value **'1'** which is equal to **49** in ASCII so if we subtract **'0'** from this which is equal to **48**, Then **converted.charAt(i) - '0'** is equal to **1** i.e **49 - 48** . SO that's why we subtract **'0'** from converted character.